# How to build JetBrains runtime from its GitHub repo?

Tags: java, jetbrains-ide

I am specifically trying to follow [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-3206/Native-Wayland-support) post. It mentions

*"build jbr21 off of nightly openjdk, e.g. OpenJDK21U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_2023-08-09-06-56.tar.gz"*

A [link](https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsRuntime/blob/main/doc/building.md) is provided to the build instructions but it is too hard for a noob to follow.

What are the steps I need to follow in order to build and run the `jbr21` branch from the JetBrains runtime repository?

Comment: Clone the repo, check out the said branch and follow the other instructions from the markdown file. Note that you need to use cygwin if you're using Windows (though I wouldn't recommend building the JDK on Windows). Also, I want to mention that building a JDK requires some time and a reasonable amount of resources if I recall correctly. What _specifically_ do you need help with?

Comment: i am running hyprland desktop (on arch linux) which uses Wayland. Intellij IDE's generally do not work on wayland, however user 'j run' from the youtrack link was able to get it running, per his screenshot. i am stille not sure what repo i need to clone. the build instructions say 'git clone https://git.openjdk.org/jdk/', 'j run' mentions OpenJDK21U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_2023-08-09-06-56.tar.gz.' None of them sound like the [jbr21 branch](https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsRuntime/tree/jbr21)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First clone the jbr repository and switch to the branch version you'd like to build.

```
git clone https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsRuntime.git
cd JetBrainsRuntime
git checkout jbr21
```

Next, follow the Build instructions in the README: https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsRuntime/tree/jbr21#configuring-the-build-environment

### Example for Linux (Docker):

Create a container:

```
$ cd jb/project/docker
$ docker build .
...
Successfully built 942ea9900054
```

Run these commands in the new container:

```
$ docker run -v `pwd`../../../../:/JetBrainsRuntime -it 942ea9900054
# cd /JetBrainsRuntime
# sh ./configure
# make images CONF=linux-x86_64-normal-server-release
```

Comment: thank you, I will try it out. quick question, how would I actually launch the IDE once it's installed?

Comment: I assume you'd copy the built jbr into the folder in the IDE. For example on Windows it's at: %programfiles%\JetBrains\<IDE>\jbr

And it sounds like you'll need to use that custom run file for the IDE that the fellow provided on youtrack.

Comment: When i try to run `sh ./configure` i get `configure: error: The path of BOOT_JDK_ARG, which resolves as "/usr/bin/java" is not found.` When i try to use the flag `--with-boot-jdk=/usr/bin/java` i get similar "path not found" error. It looks docker it is putting me into some weird shell and i don't know if it is able to 'talk' with the local directories on my machine. Note I have installed [jdk21](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/jdk-openjdk/) on my machine which has been saved in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk/.`

Comment: is it possible to build with another tool like gradle?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount

`docker run -v \`pwd\`../../../../:/JetBrainsRuntime --mount type=bind,source=/usr/bin/java,target=/usr/bin/java -it 942ea9900054`